# Avoid removing inner HTML while replacing text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to highlight the text of HTML elements without removing their inner HTML. Here is an example:

```js
const buttonEl = `<button>
  <span>
    Icon
  </span>
  Text
</button>
`;

document.body.innerHTML = buttonEl;

const foundButtonEl = document.querySelector("button");
const elements = [];

elements.push(foundButtonEl);

function addHighlight(elements, text) {
  const regex = new RegExp(text);

  elements.forEach((element, index) => {
    element.innerHTML = element.textContent.replace(
      regex,
      `<mark>$&</mark>`
    );
  });
}

addHighlight(elements, "T");
```

If you run this example, you'll notice that `T` will be highlighted, but the `<span>` tags will be removed.

How to highlight the text without affecting the inner HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.textContent` property returns (or set) the text content of all children and since the `<button>` element may contain further nested elements, its strict content might be mixed with promiscuous content coming from other elements like your span icon.

Here in this demo I added a layer that will convert the button content so that every single text node found will be removed and changed to a `span.textnode` so that later when you'll need to style the text content adding the `<mark>` it will be strightforward to change ***ONLY*** the contents of inner `span.textnode` elements.

To better show the concept I also added the fontawesome asset and style the icon inside the button.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

function addHighlight(buttons, text){
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    initButton(button);
    highlightTextInButton(button, text);
  });
}

function initButton(button){
 //for each child node in button
 for (var i = 0; i < button.childNodes.length; i++) {
    const child = button.childNodes[i];
    //if it's of type TEXT_NODE
    if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      //creates a new span.textnode
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.classList.add('textnode');
      //with this same content
      span.textContent = child.nodeValue;
      //removes the text node
      child.remove();
      //adds the new span.textnode
      button.append(span);
    }
  }
}

function highlightTextInButton(button, text){
  const regex = new RegExp(text);
  button.querySelectorAll(':scope > .textnode')
    .forEach(textnode=>{
      const textContent = textnode.textContent;
      textnode.innerHTML = textContent.replace(regex,`<mark>$&</mark>`);
    });
}

addHighlight(buttons, "T");
```

```css
.textnode{
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<button>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  Text
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You change the inner HTML of button. So one way would be to put a span around your Text and use an id and then use document.getElementById("text") I guess.
See for example

```js
const buttonEl = `<button>
    <span>
      Icon
    </span>
    <span id="text">
    Text
    </span>
  </button>
  `;

  document.body.innerHTML = buttonEl;

  const foundButtonEl = document.getElementById("text");
  const elements = [];

  elements.push(foundButtonEl);

  function addHighlight(elements, text) {
    const regex = new RegExp(text);

    elements.forEach((element, index) => {
      element.innerHTML = element.textContent.replace(
        regex,
        `<mark>$&</mark>`
      );
    });
  }

  addHighlight(elements, "T");
```

Comment: And another point is, that you use element.innerHTML = element.textContent...
Since element.textContent is only "Icon" and "Text" you also only set the innerHTML property to "Icon" and "Text".
Using your methods without changing the DOM would be to replace element.innerHTML = element.textContent.replace(...) to element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(...)
But be aware that that also might change your elements (if search text is "t" and element is button for exaple)